# Adding the vlalue in name field in task SFDC

Tags: apex, tasks

Can anyone tell me how to add the new value in the Name field in tasks object. Currently we have contact and lead I need to add one more value account in that.
Thanks

Comment: If you need to relate a task to an account, you use the `WhatId` field, labeled "Related to". The Name field is only for contacts & leads. You can't modify these fields.

Answer (score 2):

The `Name` field on the `Task` SObject (the API name for this field is `whoId`) is a standard field (one provided directly by Salesforce without the need to add it ourselves) of a special type.

When a single relationship field (think master-detail and lookup) can point to more than one type of SObject, that's called a "polymoprhic" relationship.

Generally speaking, we (by which I mean people who use Salesforce) are fairly restricted in what changes we can make to standard fields. On top of that, at time of writing (API v42.0, Spring '18) I don't believe we are given any control to create or edit polymorphic relationship fields.

So, what you're asking is currently not possible.

You could try to fake it using a combination of a custom field or two, a visualforce (or lightning) page, and some Apex, but you should really be asking yourself if the effort that would take would be worth it.

#### tl;dr

What you're asking for is currently impossible.

Comment: Thanks for your response, my requirement is very small so I hope for this overriding the page with VF doesn't make sense. Do you have any other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

"Name" field in task means WHO which refers to Contact details which is provided by Contact and Lead object only in Salesforce. You can use "related to" field means WHAT to link task to Account or create a custom field in activities or I can tell you another alternative once you share your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, when the user receive a call (Inbound) or take a Customer call,  the activity (Inbound call/outbound call) have to be created automatically under the both case and the account page. As of now the activity is only created any one of the page either account or case based on where I'm creating the task.